# Unable to test write and execute operations in emqx_lwm2m plugin in emqx V3.1.1

Tags: iot, emq

I am using Emqx V3.1.1 i have enabled emqx_lwm2m plugin and i installed wakaama client.I am able to connect to my lwm2m with 5783 port using wakaama client.(./lwm2mclient -n ep1 -h localhost -p 5783 -4).i am testing with different msg types like read discover,write,execute etc..,. I am getting proper response while sending read and discover commands. Now i am planning to test write,execute and another msg types. for this I don't have below parameters to test .

```
"type": {?ValueType},"value": {?Value},"args": {?Arguments},"pmin": {?PeriodMin},
    "pmax": {?PeriodMax},
    "gt": {?GreaterThan},
    "lt": {?LessThan},
    "st": {?Step}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example write command to set the 'Current Time':

```
{
    "path": '/3/0/13',
    "type": "Time",
    "value": 100
}
```

An example write-attr command to set the 'Minimum Period' to 10:

```
{
    "path": "/3/0/13",
    "pmin": "10"
}
```

Check out http://www.openmobilealliance.org/release/LightweightM2M to get the details of the spec.